# How can I initialize an array of a generic const length with Default?

Tags: rust

I want to initialize the array in struct A, but the array's length is a const generic. Although I can ensure the length will always be smaller than 32, it seems current compiler doesn't support this. Besides, I tried `#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked)]`, which works, but this feature has been removed from the latest compiler. Do you have any ideas?

```rust
#![feature(const_generics)]

struct B<E>
where
    E: Copy + Default,
{
    f: E,
}

struct A<E, const ITEM_NUM: usize>
where
    E: Copy + Default,
{
    array: [Option<Box<B<E>>>; ITEM_NUM],
}

impl<E, const ITEM_NUM: usize> A<E, ITEM_NUM>
where
    E: Copy + Default,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            array: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let aa = A::<i32, 12>::new();
}
```

P.S. I don't know if I can use [generic-array](https://crates.io/crates/generic-array) because the B struct also needs the E generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since const generics are still very new and `Default` is very old, it's only implemented for arrays of length less than 32. The easiest way to deal with this is to just add a bound that forces the array to implement `Default`, and that way in the future once `Default` becomes implemented for arrays of all lengths, the code will still work:

```rust
impl<E, const ITEM_NUM: usize> A<E, ITEM_NUM>
where
    E: Copy + Default,
    // require that the array implements Default
    [Option<Box<B<E>>>; ITEM_NUM]: Default,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            array: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20650e62c93d5691099923268e0e9114)